# How to completely remove tokumx from ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, tokumx

I've just installed TokuMX according to [this](https://github.com/Tokutek/mongo/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu) tutorial on my Ubuntu Server 12.04. Basically I did the following:

```
$ ls tokumx*.deb
tokumx_1.4.0-1-precise_amd64.deb  tokumx-clients_1.4.0-1-precise_amd64.deb  tokumx-common_1.4.0-1-precise_amd64.deb  tokumx-server_1.4.0-1-precise_amd64.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i tokumx*.deb

$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

All works fine. But I'm just curious how could I completely remove this one with all installed dependencies from my machine?

Comment: I believe tokumx registeres itself as `tokumx` so: `sudo apt-get remove --purge tokumx` That should remove the main package and all of its dependancies which should be the others you installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sudo apt-get purge tokumx tokumx-server tokumx-common tokumx-clients 
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```